# How to calculate a range of a date php of a billing cycle?

Tags: php, date, datetime, timestamp

I want to check if a timestamp is in a range of the billing cycle of a user in my web site. For example

If my user was registered in 03/07/2012. I would like to know if he has made more than three offers in a month of his billing cycle. for example if one day(04/09/2013) he tries to make an offer I have to finde his range.

I have stored a timestamp with his register time in mysql database. I was trying to use mktime but I cant manage the function

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Comment: That's nice. Good luck with that.

Comment: instead of using mktime if you have the date in a sane format just to strtotime

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I got you right, you know when user has registered and if now (or at any other date) he makes some action, you need to know the dates of beginning and end of billing month?

Like, if I have registered on `2012-02-04`, so at the moment my billing month would be `2013-07-04 - 2013-08-04`?

Take a look at this:

```
$registerDate = '2012-05-04';
$date = '2013-04-15';

$from = strtotime($registerDate);
$to = strtotime($date);

$interval = date_diff(date_create(date('Y-m-d H:i:s', $from)), date_create(date('Y-m-d H:i:s', $to)));

$billingMonthStart = strtotime($interval->format('-%d days'), $to);
$billingMonthEnd = strtotime('+1 month', $billingMonthStart);
```

So, now if I run

```
var_dump(@date('Y-m-d', $billingMonthStart), @date('Y-m-d', $billingMonthEnd));
```

I will get such result:

```
string(10) "2013-04-04"
string(10) "2013-05-04"
```

Is that what you have meant?

Comment: It was a great answer but it does not work perfectly. It showed me one month before.

Comment: Could you provide register date and date you want to wrap with month, so I could check?

Comment: I am sorry, it is working great. A friend tested it and he told me that. I tried again by myself and everything it is ok